# Adding an animatable blur to a view while keeping the background dynamic

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, core-graphics, uivisualeffectview

I'm trying to implement a custom blur view where the blur radius can be animated, and the blur view can stack blending modes ([CGBlendingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgblendmode) or a [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html)), all while preserving any animations/actions occurring in the background.

I tried UIVisualEffectView first, but the radius cannot be animated without accessing [private APIs](https://github.com/collinhundley/APCustomBlurView) which would most likely lead to an app rejection.

The problem with taking a snapshot and applying the effects is that the view is static, and any movement in the background is covered up by the blur view.

I also took a look at [FlexMonkey's Blurable](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Blurable), but I had similar results as the snapshot.

Any guidance would be really helpful.
Cheers

Edit: I added a gif to demonstrate what I'm trying to make. The red view moving left to right blurs and multiplies the content below it, while showing the animation occurring on the red/blue square behind it.

[image]

Comment: I might suggest trying `UIViewEffectView`, animating the alpha. It's not the same as animating the radius, but yields a decent effect (assuming your intent is to just transition from unblurred to blurred).

Comment: I tried that at first but reducing the alpha made the background look foggy instead of blurred. Ideally I would like to recreate UIVisualEffectView with control over blur radius and blending modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend modes are extremely tricky and I'm not sure it's possible to apply them to a live UIView ([GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) *might* help here) but animating the blur radius (between 0 and UIVisualEffectView's full blur) is possible via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257703/how-can-blurriness-of-uivisualeffectview-be-modified-while-dragging-in-ios/39264812#39264812):

You can animate from a `nil` effect to an effect like `UIBlurEffectStyleDark` so if we add an animation and then pause the layer's animations we can control the progress of the effect by adjusting the layer's timeOffset!

```
- (void) setupBlur {
    // Setup the blur to start with no effect
    self.blurredEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:nil];

    // Add animation to desired blur effect
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.blurredEffectView setEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
    }];

    // Pause layer animations
    self.blurredEffectView.layer.speed = 0;
}
```

Adjust blur between 0.0 and 1.0 (animation duration):

```
- (void) adjustBlur:(CGFloat)blurIntensity {
    self.blurredEffectView.layer.timeOffset = blurIntensity;
}
```

**Note:** this won't work on iOS 8 where UIBlurEffect animations aren't supported.