# A Blur on an image

Tags: swift, uiimage, blur, tvos

I tried this code on an image to blur it ... using TViOS 10.1 and Swift 3.0

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = CGRect(x: 256, y: 128, width: 1024, height: 512)
self.view.addSubview(blurView)
```

With this result... sorry this is not a blur... I am missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit the UIBlurEffect intensity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140781/how-to-edit-the-uiblureffect-intensity)

Comment: try playing with the `blurView.layer.opacity`'s __[value](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410933-opacity)__, I think that could present options for you.

Comment: Change the EffectStyle to .light. There are three choices, and my experiments with opacity failed a while back and since then found some who say do not try that. If you don't like the three choices offered, you can always use CoreImage. Fairly simple code - when applied to the image. If you need that code, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is right, Default blur view in iOS is work like this. You want more light blur view, then you should use any third party frameworks.

I used this code in my project:

```
@IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraDark)
    self.blurView.effect = blurEffect   
}
```

And the result is: [image]

Comment: Please explain to the OP *why* this works where the OP code didn't. It makes for a good answer.

Comment: Ok, but where is the blur?

Comment: Background of this screenshot is a blur view. The image shown in this screenshot is used as background image, and set a blur view above the background image. All the objects are placed on above the blur view.

Answer (score 0):

func blurEffect(){

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.blurView.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.blurView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

}

Comment: create a UIView on imageView with same size of imageView